# How to use Longitude and Latitude values from locationManager function elsewhere in my app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, openweathermap

I am using the `CoreLocation` framework to get the user's location when they open up my app. I use this function:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate


    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

}
```

to get the user's longitude and latitude position, and I can see them by printing them to the logs. This works fine.

elsewhere in my app (but in the same `viewController.swift` file) I have code that uses the OpenWeatherMap API, and I have a string that contains the url for this, which return JSON.

In my `viewDidLoad`, I use:

```
getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=XXXXXX&lon=XXXXXX&appid=(MY-APP-ID)")
```

I need to place the Long and Lat values that I've acquired in the `locationManager` function, into this string, which I know I can do by `"\()"` within the url string.

My problem is, I can currently only use these values inside the `locationManager` function. How can I store them in a value outside of this function, so I can add them into my URL string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this answers your question.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class myClass {

    var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D? // The user location as an Optional stored as a var in class "myClass". 
    // !!! This can be accessed everywhere within the class "myClass" (and deeper)

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate // Change it from var to let since it's only read not writen
        // !!! This can be accessed everywhere within the func "locationManager" (and deeper)

        userLocation = locValue // !!! Store it if necessary

        // Why would you call this in viewDidLoad? I doubt the user location will be available at this point (but it might). You can move this anywhere if you want
        // note the "\(name)" this will turn the var name into a string
        // if != nil not necessary here since it cannot be nil but still added it regardless
        // Maybe you want to add a check so this only gets called on the first location update. It depends on what you need it for.
        if userLocation != nil {
            getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(userLocation!.latitude)&lon=\(userLocation!.latitude)&appid=(MY-APP-ID)") // Why would you call this in viewDidLoad? I doubt user doubt the user location will be available at this point (but it might)
        }
        else {
            print("Error: User not Located (yet)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was gonna suggest: Don't call `getWeatherData` in `viewDidLoad`, call it once you have that data (in `locationManager...`). If you need the data elsewhere after that, why not save them in a var of your class?